# Deploy to Azure using publish profile : Works when publishing on VS2017 fails when using Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, azure, powershell, jenkins, publish-profiles

I downloaded the Publishing Profile from my App Service and created a profile on my WebApi.

When I execute "publishing" using VS 2017, it works fine. 
When I try to execute deploy command on Jenkins if fails. The error message I have is :

- Deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("XXXXXXXX") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize.
- Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
- Connected to the remote computer ("xxxxxxxxxxx") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize.
- The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I have a step on Jenkins using PowerShell command line like :

```
msbuild My.WebApi /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /P:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=$myPublishProfile
```

1. It builds without errors
2. $myPublishProfile is a valid Path
3. This Jenkins instance runs on a Server, not on my machine.
4. Jenkins has its own SMC user and server auth user.
5. App Service has *WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM* set to *False*
6. I am using the same Publishing Profile to build on Jenkins and on Visual Studio.

If both are using the same Publishing Profile, why I am getting the Auth error ?

Is there is any other config I should do to perform Deploy from Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish using visualstudio the password is stored in an encrypted file on your disk. If you need to publish with the msbuild-command you can add credentials on the commandline or in the publishprofile

append theese properties on the commandline:

```
msbuild ... /p:UserName=XXX /p:PassWord=YYY
```

or include in the profile

```
<UserName>XXX</UserName>
<Password>YYY</Password>
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. :face-palm:  Thank you D.J. !